# How to get all URLs (except for images) in Wordpress via SQL?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I need to get all of possible URLs from a Wordpress blog: post, category, pagination links - everything, except images.

I have found how to extract post URLs by using post_name and post_type functions via our database, but I can't find how to get other links that I need.

This is how I got only posts links:

```
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type="post" AND wp_posts.post_status="publish"
```

I am looking for the queries that would get all Wordpress URLs except for images.

Answer (score 1):

you can generate a sitemap of your website.

Visit https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ and copy your url website and finally you will get all the links.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! But I see it only allows up to 500 pages, is there a possibility to extract only a part of the website? Ie only the blog links?